# Java Incompatible equality constraint in list

Tags: java, generics

I have a multi level class structure and want to pass their implementation to a function that can call functions on them, but I get an `Incompatible equality constraint: Test.SubDTO2 and Test.SubDTO` error.

Here is the code:

```
public class Test {

  abstract class DTO { }

  class SubDTO extends DTO implements Interf{ }

  class SubDTO2 extends DTO implements Interf{ }

  class DAO<T extends DTO> { }

  interface Interf { }

  static DAO<SubDTO> daoImpl1;
  static DAO<SubDTO2> daoImpl2;

  public static void main(String... args) {
    func(Arrays.asList(daoImpl1, daoImpl2)); // <- error is in this line
  }

  static <T extends DTO & Interf> void func(List<DAO<T>> arg) {
  }
}
```

A more detailed example on what I try to achieve:

```
public class Test {

  abstract class DTO {
    abstract void func1();
  }

  class SubDTO extends DTO implements Interf{
    @Override
    public void func2() {
      // comes from Interf
    }

    @Override
    public void func1() {
      // comes from DTO
    }
  }

  class SubDTO2 extends DTO implements Interf{
    @Override
    public void func2() {
      // comes from Interf
    }

    @Override
    public void func1() {
      // comes from DTO
    }
  }

  class DAO<T extends DTO> {
    public T dto() {
      return null;
    }
  }

  interface Interf {
    void func2();
  }

  static DAO<SubDTO> daoImpl1;
  static DAO<SubDTO2> daoImpl2;

  public static void main(String... args) {
    func(Arrays.asList(daoImpl1, daoImpl2));
  }

  static <T extends DTO & Interf> void func(List<? extends DAO<? extends DTO>> arg) {
    arg.get(0).dto().func1(); // <- I can't call func2() here
  }
}
```

exact error message:

```
[ERROR]   required: java.util.List<Test.DAO<T>>
[ERROR]   found:    java.util.List<Test.DAO<? extends Test.DTO>>
[ERROR]   reason: inference variable T has incompatible equality constraints Test.SubDTO2,Test.SubDTO
```

I need the list in the function `func` to extend `DTO` and also implement `Interf` as well, because I call certain functions on them.

Why is this happening? It works fine if I change the signature of the `func` and pass only one `DAO`, but I need it to work with multiple.

What are my options here?

I tried it with multiple java versions (1.8+), all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should be declared like this:

```
static <T extends DTO & Interf> void func(List<DAO<? extends T>> arg) {
```

Notice that I changed `List<DAO<T>>` to `List<DAO<? extends T>>`. This is because the expression `Arrays.asList(daoImpl1, daoImpl2)` produces a value of type

```
List<DAO<? extends DTO & Interf>>
```

(Of course, this isn't real syntax for a type in Java. There's no syntax for intersection types in Java but Java does know about them when doing type inference, and you could have these types in your code if you use `var`. I use this notation here just for illustrative purposes.)

If you know [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), you'll know that this is a list of DAOs that *produces* `DTO & Interf`s/`T`s, but does not consume `DTO & Interf`s/`T`s. If you are lost at this point, please go read the PECS post - it's great. See also: [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

The reason why it does this is quite intuitive. Imagine if `DAO` is just a container for a `T`.

```
static class DAO<T extends DTO> {
    private T t;

    public T getT() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setT(T t) {
        this.t = t;
   }
}
```

If `Arrays.asList(daoImpl1, daoImpl2)` had produced a list of `DAO<DTO & Interf>` (with no `extends` or `super`), you'd be able to call `getT` *and* `setT` on elements of the list! And being able to call `setT` is especially dangerous you see - you'd be able to do this:

```
// suppose arg is a List<DAO<DTO & Interf>>
arg.get(someRandomNumber).setT(new SubDTO());
```

What if `someRandomNumber` happens to be `1`, and we get the second element, which is a `DAO<SubDTO2>`? Putting a `SubDTO` inside that destroys the whole type-safety of generics.

The only type-safe thing to do on elements of such a list like `[daoImpl1, daoImpl2]` is to use them as producers of `DTO & Interf`s, hence the type is marked `? extends DTO & Interf`. This means that if you have any methods on `DAO` that takes in a `T`, you won't be able to call them on elements of this list<sup>*</sup>.

Also note that, just in case I was not clear, it is not the list that is only a producer - the list is both a producer and consumer of `DAO`s. It's just that the `DAO`s in the list are producers of their `T`s.

---

<sup>*</sup> except by passing `null`s.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it has something to do with putting different types into the same list and that's why it was complaining, but couldn't figure out the right syntax.
Your solution works on my sample code, I will try it out on the real one tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks again!